# WordPress and add_rewrite_rule(): Assistance needed

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

On a WP website, one page grabs a slug from $_GET in order to display external news on the page. My base urls look like this
`https://exemple.com/news-and-events/news/?id=assessing/litecoins-bounce-social-supremacy-and-everything-in-between/`

I want pretty urls, like this:
`https://exemple.com/news-and-events/news/assessing/litecoins-bounce-social-supremacy-and-everything-in-between/`

I added the following in functions.php:

```
function my_rewrite() {
    add_rewrite_tag(
        '%id%',
        '([^/]+)'
    );
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^news/([^/]+)/?',
        'index.php?pagename=news&id=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_rewrite' );
```

in page.php:

```
$id = get_query_var( 'id' );
// Grab data from the endpoint using $id
```

The redirect works, but if the slug after /news/ in my url contains a slash, `get_query_var( 'id' )` **returns only the characters within the first and second slash**.

I assume the issue is in my regexp but I can't seem to make it work. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please check and post the content of `$id` after you retrieved it by `$id = get_query_var( 'id' );`

Answer (score 1):

I think you should modify the regular expression in "add_rewrite_tag" from `'([^/]+)'` to `'([^/]+/[^/]+)'`

Comment: Tried it, but still returns `["id"]=> string(7) "actifit"` while it should return `actifit/@actifit.fitness/actifit-curation-report-9-9811d1b84a53/`